# Transparent Shader not Transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders, transparency

Working with texturing/shading a spaceship in Cycles when I noticed that the transparent shader isn't being transparent.

Ship with plain diffuse:
[image]

And then ship with transparent shader applied:
[image]

Different angles shows more/less of the spaceship being in that weird blackness.